# Get Id onesignal cordova plugin

Tags: android, apache-cordova, cordova-plugin, api

estou com problemas para pegar o id do dispositivo do onesignal.

estou tentando utilizar o seguinte método:

```
var getId = function(){
window.plugins.OneSignal.getIds(function(ids) {
  alert('getIds: ' + JSON.stringify(ids));
});
}
```

Antes disso estou iniciando o onesginal e está recebendo as notificações normalmente.

```
 window.plugins.OneSignal
.startInit("APP_ID")
.handleNotificationOpened(notificationOpenedCallback)
.endInit();
```

no console está dando este erro:

> Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

Comment: Além do Cordova, qual framework você está usando?!

Comment: nenhum, apenas testando as notificações

Comment: resolvido alterei para esta meta
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * gap://ready file:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *; img-src * data: 'unsafe-inline'">

Comment: Legal, você mesmo pode inserir a resposta na sua pergunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido, quando adicionado esta tag no html resolveu o problema

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * gap://ready file:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *; img-src * data: 'unsafe-inline'">
```